# how to increase fixed divs top position by 1 each time they scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i'm trying to build a parallax scroll
where as you scroll - divs move up or down by increasing their top fixed position.

how could i create this with my code so far?

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
    $(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
           console.log('lower top fixed px');
        }
        else {
            console.log('increase top fixed px');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `$(window).scroll(...)` to call action while scrolling and `$("element").scrollTop()` or `$("element").offset().top` values to get element distance from the top, which can be helpful in determining new position.